# Remove directory from image path htaccess

Tags: php, image, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the directory `/images/` from an image path. When an image is submitted via a form it's stored in `/images/` I created a htaccess rule to remove the images directory but I'm not sure it works with images, as I get a 404.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Do I need to create a php page to serve the image and remove that page using htaccess? The goal is to have domain.com/img.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# deny direct access to /images/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /images/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# internal rewrite to add /images/ silently
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|ico)$ images%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Is it possibly to also deny access to the directory?

Comment: See updated answer for denying direct access to `/images/`.